# Is it possible to convert from MBR to GPT, keeping installation and programs?

Tags: partitioning, gpt

I have Windows 8.1 on a standard MBR partition. The actual configuration on the hard disk drive is like this:

```
Partition        Type         Size         Offset
Partition1       Primary      268GB        31 KB
Partition2       Extended     197GB        268GB
Partition3       Logical      197GB        268GB
```

Is possible to convert to GPT without losing the Windows installation and programs? Of course the BIOS supports UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

Not cheap - $50 - but [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-personal/features.html) would appear to be able to do that, without data loss - though I'd always recommend you have a backup before attempting anything like that.

> Convert basic MBR to basic GPT disks

Comment: can you confirm that this software can do it ? Because you wrote "...without data loss" , I need "...keep windows as bootable after convertion". Other software can do the conversion without data loss , but windows will not boot.

Comment: Not sure really, tbh - frankly I just assumed that if I can do it on my Mac with iPartition, you could do it on a PC with the equivalent. I've used Paragon for many tasks over the years, but never actually for that one, MBR>GPT.

Comment: The solution is Aomei Partition Assistant. I have tried with the above configuration , and he create automatically the Efi (fat32) partition , and after convert to GPT , and windows is still bootable. All these with one button click.

Comment: Followed @tiku's advice and it worked perfectly. In my case though it was a data drive, not the main system drive, so the free version worked for me. In-place conversion mbr to gpt without erasing the drive. After you click apply and reboot, it does the job in about 30 seconds. Only potential issue is anyone that dual boots might want to make sure your computer is set to boot straight into windows before starting.